# How to change the alignment of contents in a JScrollPane

Tags: java

I am working on a GUI to manage bank accounts.

I use a `JPanel` in a `JFrame` to list all the account register as buttons, and a `JScrollPane` to extend the view. When I run the program, the scroll bar appears but the buttons appears in horizontal. What do I have to the change it to appear vertical?

Comment: What `LayoutManager` do you use?

Comment: FlowLayout for the JPanel and I have fixed the dimension of the JFrame to have the buttons align on vertical.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the LayoutManager. In your case, `GridLayout` would be better. Your code can look like this:

```
// create all buttons
JButton[] buttons = { new JButton("First Button"), new JButton("Second Button"), ... };

// create the JPanel, your contentPane
JPanel p = new JPanel();
// set the LayoutManager to GridLayout and use a Grid of 1 x buttons.length
p.setLayoutManager(new GridLayout(1, buttons.length));

// add all buttons
for (JButton b : buttons)
    p.add(b);

// set the contentPane
frame.setContentPane(p);
```

Comment: OK I try it and I come back.

Answer (score -1):

It's exactly what I want but I rather use this below to get a vertical alignment :

```
// set the LayoutManager to GridLayout and use a Grid of 1 x buttons.length
p.setLayoutManager(new GridLayout(1, buttons.length));
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of my answer with a `Thanks everyone` at the end. Please accept my answer if it helped you, and don't post duplicate answers